# cannot Import Remote lambda function to ec2 via cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, cloud9

`Error importing AWS Lambda function
The following error was encountered when attempting to import your function
spawn unzip ENOENT`

that is the particular error on import,I am using ubuntu AMI

is there any method in awscli to download lambda and upload with libraries install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error when trying to import too - fixed by installing unzip on the server running Cloud9 (it was ubuntu so 'sudo apt-get install unzip').